# disabling one dropdown list on choosing values from another

Tags: jquery

I have done my homework reading similar posts (that s how I could come this close)

So, two select lists. On choosing certain values from the first one, the second selectlist should disable itself, (because it would make no sense relating to the chosen value)

So: I need an event handler which should be the 'change' and I need a function and I need to call that function when the event happens. Son when a value equal to whatever (note that it happens to be in Russian) then it should disable the second list as I said, but it is not happening. Also, there can be more than one value that could cause the second select list to go inactive.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
disableSel();
$('#object').change(disableSel);

function disableSel()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var object = $('#object').val();
        if(object === 'участок земли')
        {

            $("#term").attr("disabled", "disabled");
         }


    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: I think you'll have more homework to do, read more on [jQuery tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) and [change function](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: I have watched the 200 chapters of jquery tutorials on youtube, but...that was a long time ago..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need document.ready inside a function..use `prop()` instead of `attr()` and you have a typo there

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#object').change(disableSel); 
 });

 function disableSel()
 {
   var object = $('#object').val(); //here u missed c
    if(object === 'участок земли')
    {

        $("#term").prop("disabled", true);
     }
 }
```

or using only change event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#object').change(function(){
        var object = $(this).val(); 
        if(object === 'участок земли')
       {

          $("#term").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }); 
 });
```

Comment: I mean I give you the right answer, even though I dont know why it is not working in my case :( could it be because of the Russian stuff? it is displaying ok on the page as I put lang = ru and utf-8

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#select1').change(function(){
 if($(this).val() == "your value")
    $("#select2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

or

```
 $('#select1').change(function(){
 if($(this).val() == "your value")
    $("#select2").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: @user1961282 did you got the solution with my answer

Comment: @Sashenka. Bless you! you made me realize why I was not making it work by showing a working example. Thank you a heaven much! you helped greatly someone !

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#object').change(function() {
        if (this.value == "your val") {
            $("#term").prop("disabled", true);
        }  
    });
});
```